# CASE WHEN DATE not providing correct results

Tags: sql-server, select, date, case

When using the below query the "Result_field" returns "NO" even if the date is greater than 12/31/2020.  How can I get it to show "YES" when the date is greater than 12/31/2020 and "NO" When Less Than?  Been trying to research this for a while and now need help.  This may be a simple query, but I'm kinda new at this.  Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT Date_field,
CASE 
    WHEN Date_field < '2020-12-31' THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES'
    end as Result_field
FROM Yearly_Report;
```

This is the result I get:

[image: Result Image]

Comment: Is `Date_field` actually a string column? If so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the table definition, this is kind of an educated guess, but it looks like your Date_Field is a string field (VARCHAR, NVARCHAR etc) instead of a DATE or DATETIME field.

As per [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=104a4b8ac43f82968f99667640ab0243), when defined as a VARCHAR field the results are all "NO" because the comparison is a string to string and doesn't make any sense (one string cannot be less than another string). When defined as a DATE field, the comparison value is implicitly converted to a DATE value and then can be successfully compared.

The correct solution would probably be to change the data type of the Date_Field column to DATE or DATETIME, however, if this isn't possible you can resolve this in the query alone using TRY_PARSE:

```
SELECT DateField,
CASE 
    WHEN TRY_PARSE(DateField AS DATE USING 'en-US') < '2020-12-31' THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES'
    end as ResultField
FROM Dates;
```

You can see the results in the fiddle are as expected:

```
DateField   ResultField
-----------------------
06/30/2022  YES
06/30/2018  NO
12/31/2022  YES
06/30/2020  NO
09/30/2020  NO
03/31/2020  NO
03/31/2024  YES
06/30/2021  YES
```

Comment: `DATE is deprecated` --> what?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I thought I had read somewhere that the DATE data type was being deprecated, but I can't find the article any more. Updated the answer and removed this.

Comment: @HandyD, that article was about _datetime_ probably. There is a note in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: @HandyD. Unfortunately the work around did not work for me.  After trying I received an error.  **Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 470
TRY_PARSE is not a recognized built-in function name.**  It looks like the Database  compatibility is only 2008.

Comment: I'm not the owner of the Database or Table creator.  I'm only running a few reports and don't want to update the table. I do understand why it's not working on my end.  If there are any other workaround I can use, please let me know.

Comment: In SQL 2012 the TRY_* functions were introduced to prevent a whole query failing if some records couldn't be converted/parsed as the desired data type. Try just using PARSE instead which should be available in 2008. The obvious disadvantage is if any of the values aren't able to be parsed as datetime this will fail the whole query but hopefully, it will work.